# Inside a conda enviroment, GNU parallel jobs stop starting new jobs when I close the terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, nohup, gnu-parallel

It is inside Conda environment (prokka, so actually, I am using the parallel version which is a prokka dependency)

My code is written in a file named **test.sh**, then I

```
nohup parallel -k -j 10 < test.sh >test.log &
```

while inside the **test.sh**, it is:

```
echo file1; sleep 50
echo file2; sleep 50
echo file3; sleep 50
...
echo file99; sleep 50
```

When I closed the terminal, it said parallel will not start new jobs:

```
$ cat test.log
parallel: SIGHUP received. No new jobs will be started.
parallel: Waiting for these 10 jobs to finish. Send SIGTERM to stop now.
parallel: echo file1; sleep 50
parallel: echo file2; sleep 50
parallel: echo file3; sleep 50
parallel: echo file4; sleep 50
parallel: echo file5; sleep 50
parallel: echo file6; sleep 50
parallel: echo file7; sleep 50
parallel: echo file8; sleep 50
parallel: echo file9; sleep 50
parallel: echo file10; sleep 50
file1
file2
file3
file4
file5
file6
file7
file8
file9
file10
```

Is the code wrong? Can't find a explanation from the internet. The parallel version I am using is 20201122.

Follow-up: Dealt when I just exit and in the base environment of conda.

Comment: See if you can make an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: As a workaround look at GNU screen or tmux.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour you see. I think it depends on your environment or distribution. Please see if you can reproduce it on a VM: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#REPORTING-BUGS

Comment: @OleTange Since you don't have this error, I think very hard again to find that maybe because I am inside a conda environment. Now it worked, when I am just in the base environment of conda. Don't know why, but thanks to that, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Is it because
"SIGTERM is changed to SIGHUP, so sending SIGHUP will make GNU Parallel start no more jobs, but wait for running jobs to finish." ?

If you log out, then the SIGHUP signal will send to parallel. It will not start more jobs.

https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=9401